# Create a tab in Windows Terminal that is run as a different user?

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-terminal

So I can run...

`runas /user:PNG\SomeSvc "cmd /c ^"powershell.exe^""`

And get a powershell prompt that's run by a different user.

But if I'm using Windows Terminal and I want to run it as a different user, how would I do that?  I'm sure it probably has something to do with the json configuration file.

Also, is there anything I would need to use for authentication if I store the file in a secure string or "Windows Credential Manager" via the `New-StoredCredential` commandlet?

Answer (score 2):

<sub>*As mentioned in the comments, my answer below mistakenly only addresses how to run an elevated, administrative tab or Terminal. If you are searching, as the OP was, for how to do this with any user, it does not answer that. Leaving the answer in place since it has seemed to help someone with at least a different goal, but I don't have an answer right now to how to do this for a different user.*</sub>

Your question title and the question body don't feel *quite* aligned to me.  The question title asks:

> Create a tab in Windows Terminal that is run as a different user?

But your question body (and the existing PowerShell example) seem to be slightly different:

> But if I'm using Windows Terminal and I want to run it as a different user, how would I do that?

Since I can't quite be sure if you want *one* tab in Windows Terminal to be elevated, or if you just want to launch Windows Terminal as elevated, I'll answer both:

##### Elevating a single tab

You can't UAC-elevate your user for a single tab.  See Windows Terminal Github [Issue #632](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/632) and [#691](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal/issues/691) for more info.  Warning, #632 is a very long read.

You can probably get around this with some combination of PowerShell remoting and/or OpenSSH.  I did a few quick tests since I have Windows OpenSSH server already enabled:

- Enabled Windows Administrator (which I promptly disabled again after trying this)
- Set a password on the Administrator account
- `ssh`'d in to `localhost` as my regular user
- Start PowerShell or PowerShell core (I already have it set as my default OpenSSH shell)
- `$cred = New-Object -type System.Management.Automation.PSCredential "Administrator", (Read-host -AsSecureString)`
- `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName localhost -Credential $cred`
- `whoami` results in `computername\Administrator`

Note `Enter-PSSession -ComputerName localhost` won't work directly from a Windows Terminal tab since it (chicken-and-the-egg) requires that it be elevated ...

##### Elevating Windows Terminal

However, it is quite easy to start a new Windows Terminal process that is elevated.

My usually command for doing this is, from PowerShell:

```
Start-Process wt -Verb RunAs
```

You can also "Run as Administrator" from the Start Menu or pinned Taskbar entry.  This will, of course, bring up the UAC prompt.

I haven't tried this, but if you wanted to run `wt.exe` with the Administrator credentials, you would at least need to:

- Enable the Administrator account with a password
- Log in to Windows with that account
- Install Windows Terminal from the Store

Otherwise, that user won't have it installed in their account anyway.

Or you can circumvent that by installing the non-Store version of Windows Terminal.  Note, however, that Microsoft considers this an "unsupported" configuration.

Comment: Elevating (run as Administrator) is not the same thing as running as a different user.  OP was quite specifically looking as how to run as a specific different user.

Comment: @dunxd That's a good point, and one that I clearly didn't catch three years ago.  I was so focused on the nuance between running one tab and multiple tabs that I missed that the user just wanted a different user rather than an administrative account.  I've edited the answer to make this clear at the start, so that other's don't read the whole thing and waste their time. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: I figured out that Windows Terminal allows defining different profiles, and you can include runas in the Command line. I added this as a new answer - your answer as people might be looking for either or both options.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the sysinternals available then you can use

```
PS> psexec -h \\local powershell
```

from a non-admin terminal. However this results in weird terminal behavior so it is probably better to just use `PS> psexec -h \\local <command>` to just run the single command you want as admin.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a profile that runs under a specific different user using [runas](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/it-pro/windows-server-2012-R2-and-2012/cc771525(v=ws.11)) in the Command line.

Open settings, and click *Add a new profile*. It is easier if you duplicate one of the existing profiles. In the command line box edit it to include runas, specify the user, and enclose the existing command in quotes. For example:

`runas.exe /user:user@domain.com "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh"`

Then name the profile.  You can now open a new tab using that profile and it will immediately ask you for the password for user@domain.com, and run subsequent commands as that user.

You can also select to *Run this profile as Administrator*.